# Who were Jedi Temple Guards?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

In the last episode of last season (5) of *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*, I encountered a new category of *guards*. They were placed in the Jedi Temple & were using lightsabers.
[image: Jedi Temple Guards]
[image: Jedi Temple Guards stopping Anakin Skywalker]
[image: Jedi Temple Guards escorting Jedi prisoner]

As far as I know, Jedi had a high-tier of identity who couldn't be placed under mask as security puppets (Even clone troopers used to speak freely, but these Jedi temple guards were fully silent even when Jedi were discussing something). So, it seems unlikely to me that they were Jedi.

But, as they were using lightsabers (although, it was never displayed how  efficiently they could use them), so it seems unlikely to me that they weren't force sensitive.

They also don't look like robots using lightsabers.

Who were they, really? Have they ever appeared in canon before?

Comment: FYI: We saw some canon examples of non-Force-sensitives using lightsabers (General Grevious)

Comment: @DVK Grevious wields lightsaber more with his robotic attributes rather than his organic instinct.

Comment: @SachinShekhar There's [Pre Vizsla](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Pre_Vizsla) from the Clone Wars series who used a darksaber. He fought fairly well against Kenobi, although he eventually lost. He was also good enough to last against Darth Maul although he didn't survive.

Comment: @Yawus Nice example, but still such type of extraordinary guys were rare. And yet, he never won against a force user in saber duel. I think, guarding Jedi Temple was an important job.

Comment: @SachinShekhar Well, I was just pointing out the possibility of non-Force-sensitives wielding a lightsaber despite no robotic enhancements. It's most likely the guards are Force-sensitive Jedi.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Temple_Guard):

> The Jedi Temple Guards were members of the Jedi Order and served in the Coruscant Jedi Temple's Security Force.

From [starwars.com](https://starwars.com/explore/encyclopedia/groups/jedi-temple-guard/):

> An ancient, honored heritage within the hallowed halls of the Jedi Temple was the role of the Jedi Temple Guard. Reporting to Cin Drallig, head of security, the Temple Guards were anonymous sentinels plucked from the ranks of the Jedi as part of a Knight's ongoing commitment to the Order. A Jedi Temple Guard would disappear inside the formal robes and identity-concealing masks, the ultimate expression of emotional detachment required in service to a higher calling. Temple Guards carried imposing lightsaber pikes -- thick, double-bladed weapons that produced a rare and distinctive yellow blade.

The Wookieepedia description was sourced almost exactly from the starwars.com page. But they apparently were force-sensitive, being they were actually Jedi.

Comment: +1. I think that's canon, but I asked separately just in case, as it was just my assumption that it is: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32520/how-canonical-is-information-appearing-on-main-starwars-com-pages